# UV unwrapping an object according to a tga. file?

Tags: uv

So I have an obj. of a CSGO weapon model and its unwrapped tga. file, however, the weapon unwraps itself differently to the tga. file. Is there any way to tell Blender to unwrap the model according to the tga. file or would I have to do it manually? Thanks.

Comment: *the weapon unwraps itself differently to the tga. file* that's not how it's working. If model has texture it should be already unwrapped and have UV map especially if it's coming from game engine. In that case all you need to do is to use that UV map by plugging texture into shader. No need to unwrap it once more. *would I have to do it manually* if you unwrapped it and overwritten the original then yes

Comment: I was working with an animation, not the actual obj. of the gun, but yes, it seems like I have manually unwrapped it again, so I recovered some past version and it unwraps itself properly now. Thanks.